# Flutter: How to update model item inside list

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary

I have a `List<Items> items` of model Items

```
class Items {
 String name;
 String? value;
 String price;
}
```

And i have a `Map<String, String> values` witch contains values for model. As a key it uses same data as `Items.name` and value of it contains data.

So my question is. How can i update my `items` list with added value data from `values` map? Basically, list of `items` contains only required field name. Later i get values for it and place it inside map. Now i want to update my list with added value data

Comment: sorry, but what you're saying isn't clear. Kindly edit the question and explain it in a simpler and more meaningful way. Also, add an example if you're not able to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you structure the class to accept the `Map<String, String> values`:

```html
class Item {
  String? name;
  String? value;

  Item({this.name, this.value});

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['name'] = name;
    data['value'] = value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

If this is your map:

```html
Map<String, String> values = {"name": "wambua", "value": "Programmer"};
```

This is how you map the map to the class:

```html
Item.fromJson(values);
```

Comment: I updated my Items model in question. I want to only update value field without changing other data

Comment: Then you can traverse the map and set `String value` value this way in the Item object: `item.value = values['value'];` .